# Has there been an applications of search and matching theory in the Neoclassical Growth Model?

Tags: macroeconomics, labor-economics, economic-growth, unemployment, search-and-matching

Specifically, I am looking for the standard neoclassical growth model, but the labour decision is based on either search or matching theory instead of a Walrasian labour mechanism.

Comment: I am currently looking for a similar model. Did you ever find some references? The closest I could come to is A three state model of worker flows in general equilibrium (Krusell, Mukoyama, Rogerson, Sahin), but they fail to include a matching function.

Answer (score 1):

Search and matching models are fairly standard in macroeconomics. I guess this is fair to say since [Peter Diamond, Dale Mortensen, and Christopher Pissarides won the Nobel prize in 2010](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/economic-sciences/2010/press-release/). These are the names behind the canonical DMP model that most graduate students have to study in their first year. Although I am not a macroeconomist, I am confident to say that search models recognized as a key ingredient to explain unemployment in equilibrium. I suggest to watch the interview with Per Krusell on the Nobel prize homepage and read the [scientific background](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/economic-sciences/2010/advanced-information/).